# setting path variable ins puppet manifest

Tags: puppet

I have a build script that i want to use using puppet manifest. The ant build script needs to have the following environment variables setup for it to function. Reading online there is no good way for puppet to setup the variables for path. Any suggestions.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
export SERVICEMIX_HOME=/opt/apache-servicemix-3.3.2
export ANT_HOME=/opt/opt/apache-ant-1.8.4
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$SERVICEMIX_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

once these are setup then i can call an EXEC in puppet with ant all or some other build script.

Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Type Reference = exec](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec) (Take note of 'environment')
Something like this should work:

```
exec { 'my_nifty_command.sh':
  environment => [JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26, CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37, SERVICEMIX_HOME=/opt/apache-servicemix-3.3.2, ANT_HOME=/opt/opt/apache-ant-1.8.4 ],
  path        => "$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$SERVICEMIX_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH"
}
```

Comment: The quotation marks should be reversed from their use here. Strings with evaluated variables need double quotes, and strings without evaluated variables should use single quotes (to skip checking for evaluation) - http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_datatypes.html#strings

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

for example try setting your environment variables persistently by modifying e.g /etc/environment

```
file { "/etc/environment":
    [...]
    content => inline_template("JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26\nCATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37\nSERVICEMIX_HOME=/opt/apache-servicemix-3.3.2\nANT_HOME=/opt/opt/apache-ant-1.8.4\nPATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$SERVICEMIX_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH"),
}
```

Yes it is a very ugly snippet, but just for getting the idea. It is the basic approach.
I advice to separate data from puppet code, by getting your variable's content (data) from hiera.

Regards
ITL